# Dynamically Resize Video in a QGraphicScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qmediaplayer

So I have a QMediaPlayer playing video it is contained inside of a QGraphicsVideoItem, inside of a QGraphicsScene. I also have text inside of the QGraphicsScene. The QGraphicsView resizes to the size of the text, but not the video so I can only see the upper left corner of the video.

Is there a way to cause the video to stretch to fill the space available? And is there a way to centre the video in the space available, instead of being stuck in the upper left corner?

Below is my current code.

```
videoWidget = new VideoWidget();
QGraphicsView* graphicsView = new QGraphicsView(videoWidget);
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(graphicsView);
QGraphicsVideoItem* videoItem = new QGraphicsVideoItem();
QGraphicsTextItem* text = new QGraphicsTextItem("Lorem ipsum ");

text->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::white);
graphicsView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
graphicsView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

player = new QMediaPlayer();
player->setVideoOutput(videoItem);

graphicsView->setScene(scene);
graphicsView->scene()->addItem(videoItem);
graphicsView->scene()->addItem(text);

playlist = new QMediaPlaylist();
playlist->setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::Loop);
player->setPlaylist(playlist);

playlistModel = new PlaylistModel();
playlistModel->setPlaylist(playlist);`
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a way to resize the video, basically I instantiated the resizeEvent in the videoWidget so that it would update the sizes of the Graphics Items.

```
void VideoWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
  QSize size = event->size();

  if(graphicsView != NULL)
    {//Changes the size of the area the video can display in
      graphicsView->setMinimumSize(size);
      graphicsView->setMaximumSize(size);
    }
  if(graphicsVideoItem != NULL)
    {//This changes the size/pos of the video itself
      graphicsVideoItem->setSize(size);
    }
  QVideoWidget::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

Where `class VideoWidget : public QVideoWidget`